# Creating list of times from 7:30 to 22:30

Tags: r, date, time, format

I'm trying to create list of dateTimes from  2015-04-18 to 2015-11-13 (Saturdays and Sundays only), with the times of 7:00 to 22:30 . The code I have so far is:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-04-18"),as.Date("2015-11-13"),1)
weekdays<- weekdays(dates)
times<-format(seq(as.POSIXct("2015-04-18 7:30:00"),as.POSIXct("2015-04-18 22:30:00"),by="30 min"),format="%H:%M")
res <- data.frame(dates,weekdays)
res<-res[res$weekdays=="Sunday" | res$weekdays=="Saturday",]
```

The `paste()` function won't work because it 'recycles' the values. So, basically I want a set of values that looks like this:

```
"2015-10-03 7:30 PDT"
"2015-10-03 8:00 PDT"
"2015-10-03 8:30 PDT"
"2015-10-03 9:00 PDT"
etc
```

For each day in the sequence. I have a feeling it is an `apply()` function that will accomplish this but I'm not proficient with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid` to find all combinations:

```
combo <- with(expand.grid(as.character(times), as.character(res$dates)), paste(Var2, Var1))
head(combo)
# [1] "2015-04-18 07:30" "2015-04-18 08:00" "2015-04-18 08:30" "2015-04-18 09:00" "2015-04-18 09:30"
# [6] "2015-04-18 10:00"
```